# Is there a way to have jPlayer's timeupdate execute only once a second?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer, scrolltop

I am trying to create a pop out div (related-products) of items related to specific times in a video with jPlayer.  Here is my code:

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").bind($.jPlayer.event.timeupdate, function(event) {
            var requestProducts = xml.getElementsByTagName("product");

            for(var i = 0; i < requestProducts.length; i++){
                var mark = (requestProducts[i].getElementsByTagName("mark")[0].childNodes[0] == undefined) ? '' : requestProducts[i].getElementsByTagName("mark")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                var item_name = (requestProducts[i].getElementsByTagName("item_name")[0].childNodes[0] == undefined) ? '' : requestProducts[i].getElementsByTagName("item_name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                var item_url = (requestProducts[i].getElementsByTagName("item_url")[0].childNodes[0] == undefined) ? '' : requestProducts[i].getElementsByTagName("item_url")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                var item_thumb_url = (requestProducts[i].getElementsByTagName("item_thumb_url")[0].childNodes[0] == undefined) ? '' : requestProducts[i].getElementsByTagName("item_thumb_url")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                var newItem = ("<li><a href='"+item_url+"' target='_blank'><img src='"+item_thumb_url+"'><br /><strong>"+item_name+"</strong></a></li>");

                if ($.jPlayer.convertTime(event.jPlayer.status.currentTime) == mark){
                    if (i < 1){
                        $("#related-products").css('display','block');
                        $("#related-products").html("<h4>Related Products</h4><ul class='slider'></ul>");
                    }
                    $(".slider").append(newItem);
                    $("#related-products").scrollTop(208*i);
                }
            }
            });
```

I am using the jPlayer event timeupdate along with convertTime to get the time in seconds to match a preset time (mark) for each item to be displayed.  The problem I am having is that timeupdate returns 8 times per second, so the items are being added 8 times instead of just once.  If I change the code to `if ($.jPlayer.convertTime(event.jPlayer.status.currentTime) > timecode){` it will add each item only once, but then it will continually execute `$("#related-products").scrollTop(208*i);` so the scrolling of items in the div doesn't work properly.  Is there a way to either get timeupdate to happen only once a second or to get `$("#related-products").scrollTop(208*i);` to only happen once?  I am a bit of a noob at this, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean to know if you already did your function call or not.